# Creating order without shipping/delivery

Tags: intershop

We need to create Intershop order with product that doesn't require delivery (mobile network plan with monthly payments). As far as we know each basket and order requires to have a shipping method and addresses for it.

Is there a way to avoid setting shipping method or addresses on basket and order since we are not using it, or to setup a shipping method that requires no address.

We also tried to skip setting shipping method on basket and create order with it but it failed.

Also we have tried searching Intershop documentation for digital products and there were a few mentions only of digital addresses but no further info could be found that is relevant to our case.

EDIT: We are not using PWA and we do have physical products (mobile phones) for which we are using standard shipping methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To totally circumvent shipping method and shipping address might be quite hard. Are you using PWA? Are there only digital products in your system?

The imho easiest way to achieve something similar out of the box is to use FreightClass "DIGITALDELIVERY" for your products. You will still need to add a shipping address, but an email on that shipping address should be enough (maybe just take over from invoice address? it will then belong to destination region "email-addresses"). Then shipping method "E-mail Delivery" should be available.

Comment: Thanks for the info. We are not using PWA, and we do have physical products like mobile phones (will update the question).
DIGITALDELIVERY freight class looks like something we need, will definitelly look into it.